# Emulating wildcard searches using Lucene-based search on Cloudant

Tags: search, lucene, cloudant

Lucene does not permit use of a * or ? symbol [as the first character of a search](http://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/queryparsersyntax.html) when going through the query parser. Although lucene permits the use of wildcards at the start for other implementations [such as lucene.net](http://manfredlange.blogspot.com/2010/07/wildcard-searches-in-lucenenet.html), this query parser quirk also flows into [Cloudant's Lucene-based search](https://cloudant.com/for-developers/search/).

Lets say we want to emulate: `q=foo:*`

Can this be specified as: `q=foo:([\u0000 TO \uffff] OR [-Infinity TO Infinity])`

and the negation as 
`q=*:* AND NOT foo:([\u0000 TO \uffff] OR [-Infinity TO Infinity])`

Comment: Can you describe what you're trying to achieve? If you are attempting to find documents where "foo" exists, you could index a boolean value and search for fooExists:true?

Comment: If any field can be wildcarded, wouldn't shadowing each field with "Exists" double the index size? Is it more expensive to query using the approach in my question as compared to having a separate "Exists" field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to add an index which names the included field names. For example:

```
function(doc) {
   var included = [];
   if(doc.foo) {
       index("foo", doc.foo);
       included.push("foo");
   }

   if(doc.bar) {
       index("bar", doc.bar);
       included.push("bar");
   }

   if(included.length > 0) {
       index("has", included.join(" "));
   }
}
```

You could then use

```
?q=has:foo
```

to find all docs with a foo field.